# Creating Updateable App Without The Need For Full Update - On Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

Currently creating an app in C# on Xamarin and have hit a brick wall. I have created apps before but when completed they were completed, it's different this time.

I'm currently creating an app which requires data to be updated weekly.

Essentially I have a txt file which is currently part of the app, this txt file is split up with each 'line' in the file being added to a list to show data in a listview.

What I need to know is how to make the app so that this txt file can be updated on a weekly basis without the need for a full new app download (who would want to do that every week?).

Thanks in advance for any help offered.

Comment: Sounds like a simple service to me. Just consume the service and handle the updates weekly. If you want I can provide you with some examples :)

Comment: Hi Idev Dev. I'm sure it would be pretty simple as it would be updated literally once a week. Any examples you could provide would be a massive help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to update some file weekly the best way is to consume rest services. Xamarin.forms has made this pretty simple.

You should give a try to take a look at these examples provided my xamarin documentation : [consuming rest services](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/cloud-services/consuming/rest/) and [this link is pretty useful too.](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/) If you are looking at more detailed example I can provide you with one. :)

Comment: Thank you so much for this. If you send me some more detailed examples that would be great as well as it's something I'll be doing increasing often in future :)

Comment: No problem at all. If you need any help, or get stuck somewhere just ask. Happy coding :)